# Closed form of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{(x^2 - 7x + 10)(x^2 + 1)} dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, solution-verification, closed-form, residue-calculus

> Find the closed form for the integral $$\mathcal I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{(x^2 - 7x + 10)(x^2 + 1)} dx$$

**My attempt**

In order to solve this integral, what I first consider is using residue theory. First of all, notice that

- The denominator cancels out when $x^2 - 7x + 10 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x = \frac{7 \pm \sqrt{7^2 - 40}}{2} = \begin{cases} x_1 = 2 \\ x_2 = 5 \end{cases}$, as well as when $x^2 + 1 = 0 \Leftrightarrow x=\pm i$. Notice that the poles $2$ and $5$ are placed on the real axis, and the only one on the upper semiplane is $i$.
- From Euler's identity we know that $e^{i \pi x} = \cos(\pi x) + i \sin(\pi x)$. Therefore, we can rewrite the integral as
  $$\Im \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{\pi z}}{(z^2 - 7z + 10)(z^2 + 1)} dz \right) = \Im \left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i\pi z}}{(z-2)(z-5)(z+i)(z-i)} dz \right)$$
  From residue theory, we know that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{i\pi z}}{(z-2)(z-5)(z+i)(z-i)} dz = 2\pi i Res(f(z); z=i) + \pi i Res(f(z); z=2) + \pi i Res(f(z); z=5)$$

Now were I'm not confident is calculating the residues. I can apply that, as all the poles are simple,
$$Res(f(z); z=i) =  \lim_{z\to i} (z-i) f(z) = \lim_{z\to i} \frac{e^{i\pi z}}{(z-2)(z-5)(z+i)} = \frac{e^{-\pi}}{18i + 14}$$
$$Res(f(z); z=2) =  \lim_{z\to 2} (z-2) f(z) = \lim_{z\to 2} \frac{e^{i\pi z}}{(z-i)(z-5)(z+i)} = \frac{-e^{2i\pi}}{15}$$
$$Res(f(z); z=5) =  \lim_{z\to 5} (z-5) f(z) = \lim_{z\to 5} \frac{e^{i\pi z}}{(z-i)(z-2)(z+i)} = \frac{e^{5i\pi}}{78}$$
So
$$\mathcal I=\Im \left(2\pi i \frac{e^{-\pi}}{18i + 14} + \pi i \frac{-e^{2i\pi}}{15} + \pi i \frac{e^{5i\pi}}{78} \right)$$

From here I have two concerns:

1. How can I simpify the resulting expresion of the integral, if it is indeed the correct answer.
2. In my previous post for an integral, I was said that the residues are indeed the terms of the Taylor expresion (since in this integral the poles are simple, they would be the $0^{th}$ term?), but I could not figure out how to find them that way, if someone could explain me that method.

Thanks so much for the helping:)

Comment: One mistake I see is that the sign for the residue for $z=5$ is wrong. It should be $+\frac{e^{5i\pi}}{78}$, not $-\frac{e^{5i\pi}}{78}$.

Comment: You’re right, my bad I’ll edit that thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Since $e^{2 \pi i k} = (-1)^k$ for $k \in \Bbb Z$, the second and third terms of the expression in $\Im(\cdots)$ are purely imaginary. We can compute the imaginary part of the first term by rewriting it in the form $a + b i$, by multiplying both the numerator and denominator of the fraction by the conjugate $14 - 18 i$ of the denominator.

More generally, if $a, b \in \Bbb R$ are distinct, the computation gives for
$$f(x) := \frac{\sin \pi x \,dx}{(x - a) (x - b) (x^2 + 1)}$$
that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{PV}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \,dx
&= \Im \left(2 \pi i \left[\operatorname{Res}(f(z), i) + \frac{1}{2} \operatorname{Res}(f(z), a) + \operatorname{Res}(f(z), b)\right] \right) \\
&= \pi \Im \left[\frac{e^{-\pi}}{(i - a)(i - b)} + \frac{i e^{\pi i a}}{(a - b)(a^2 + 1)} - \frac{i e^{\pi i b}}{(a - b)(b^2 + 1)}\right] \\
&= \frac{\pi [ e^{-\pi} (a^2 - b^2) + (1 + b^2) \cos \pi a - (1 + a^2) \cos \pi b]}{(a - b) (1 + a^2) (1 + b^2)}
\end{align*}
In the special case that $a, b \in \Bbb Z$, the second and third terms in the numerator are $(1 + b^2) (-1)^a$ and $-(1 + a^2) (-1)^b$, repectively. Specializing to the integral at hand, i.e., the case $a = 2, b = 5$, gives a value of
$$\frac{\pi}{390}\left(21 e^{-\pi} - 31\right) = -0.24240\ldots,$$
which agrees with your numerical evaluation.

(2) It's not entirely clear what this question is asking, but perhaps the following will clarify the issue: If $f(z)$ has a simple pole at $z = z_0$, its Laurent expansion is $$\frac{b_{-1}}{z - z_0} + a_0 + a_1(z - z_0) + \cdots ,$$ where $b_{-1} = \operatorname{Res}(f, z_0)$, and so $(z - z_0) f(z)$ (with the singularity at $z = z_0$ removed) has a Taylor series defined at $z = z_0$, namely,
$$b_{-1} + a_0 (z - z_0) + a_1 (z - z_0)^2 + \cdots .$$
In particular, $\operatorname{Res}(f, z_0) = b_{-1} = \lim_{z \to z_0} (z - z_0) f(z)$.

Answer (score 4):

*A solution using only algebra.*

$$\mathcal I= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin (\pi x)}{(x^2 - 7x + 10)(x^2 + 1)} dx$$ Write
$$A= \frac{1}{(x^2 - 7x + 10)(x^2 + 1)}=\frac 1{(x-2)(x-5)(x+i)(x-i)}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition
$$A=\frac{1}{78 (x-5)}-\frac{1}{15 (x-2)}+\frac{7-9i }{260(x-i) }+\frac{7+9i }{260(x+i) }$$ So, we first face four antiderivatives
$$J(a)=\int \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{x-a}\,dx=\int  \frac{\sin(\pi(t+a ))}{t}\,dt$$ Expanding the sine and integrating
$$J(a)=\sin (\pi  a)\, \text{Ci}(\pi  (x-a))+\cos (\pi  a) \,\text{Si}(\pi (x-a))$$

Recombining everything, back to $\mathcal I$ and the limits
$$\mathcal I=\frac{\pi}{780}   (21 \cosh (\pi )-31)-\frac{\pi }{780}  (31+42 \sinh (\pi )-21 \cosh (\pi ))$$ $$\mathcal I=\frac{\pi}{390} \left(21 e^{-\pi }-31\right) $$